# How should we [title] tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

I recently noticed that the [titles](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/titles) tag is being used inconsistently. The tag wiki excerpt says:

> Questions dealing with title/honorifics of certain characters in SFF works.

But while some of the tagged questions are indeed about titles of fictional characters:

- [Why are Stannis and Renly never referred to as "Prince"?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/139483/31394)
- [What's the origin of referring to female superior officers as "sir"?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/100640/31394)
- [What Does the Title "Ama" Mean in Wicked?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/27759/31394)

... others are about titles of *works* of sci-fi or fantasy instead:

- [Why is Cloud Atlas named 'Cloud Atlas'?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/48776/31394)
- [Why the title "Goblet of Fire" for book 4?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/102879/31394)
- [What specifically does the "awakens" in "The Force Awakens" refer to?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/110975/31394)

The questions tagged [titles](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/titles) are roughly evenly split (8 vs 9) between these two different types of usage. Either one would be fine as a way of using a tag called [titles](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/titles), but we can't really keep using both: **a given tag should have a single clear, unambiguous usage guidance.**

Let's make a decision on this. There are few enough questions with this tag that it won't take long to retag half of them by hand if necessary.

### How do we want to use the [titles](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/titles) tag?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm surprised this tag even exists.

We also have the problem that it's not being used everywhere it could be. [There's about 3 dozen more questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=Title%3Atitle%20is%3Aq%20-%5B*ident*%5D%20-%5Btitles%5D) that could potentially have the tag.

We already have [names](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/names), which may be the best solution here.

Currently, [names](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/names) doesn't have a usage guidance. Instead of [defining how the tag should be used](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214338/287266), it defines what a name is.

**We could fix these problems in one go by changing all honorific/ranks usage of [titles](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/titles) into [names](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/names) and adding the usage guidance of:**

> For questions about the names and titles of characters, including honorifics; names of cities and locations; or names of vessels, weapons and and objects. Questions can be in-universe or out-of-universe about topics such as origins, meanings, usage and pronunciations. *

And then slowly adding [names](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/names) to those questions missing any such tag.

By having the tag encompass a larger variety of "names", it should make the tag easier to find and more likely to be used consistently. We could have [honorifics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/honorifics) plus [names](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/names), but I think we'd end up seeing them used incorrectly or not at all. Another reason I don't see more specific tags being generally useful is they're all *intimately* tied to being used alongside a specific work tag.

*Wording suggestions welcome. I just wrote something quickly that captures how we're *already* using [names](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/names) and [titles](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/titles).

---

As for the remaining questions about the actual titles of a work, I think the tag should be renamed. I'm a little against [story-title](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-title), just because of the [hundreds of story-id questions asking about titles](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=Title%3Atitle%20is%3Aq%20%5B*ident*%5D%20), and feel that it *may* be used in place of or with *-identification where it doesn't fit. As an alternative, I think we could rename it to [title-explanation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/title-explanation) and have usage guidance of:

> For questions about the meanings, origins and pronunciations of the titles of works, including books, chapters and songs.

Comment: I agree with merging the "honorifics" meaning of [tag:titles] into the existing [tag:names] tag. Not sure if I agree with lumping the "story-titles" meaning in there though. Questions about names/titles of characters or in-universe objects or locations and questions about titles of stories tend to be quite different and require different types of answers.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Agreed with you, don't lump in "story-titles" with "name-titles".

Comment: Only problem keeping the tags separate is continued misuse. If a rename can improve it, go for it. But "story-titles" is bound to be misused with story-id, so we should use something else.

Comment: @CreationEdge Past history suggests that that misuse would be a drop in the ocean compared to the number of people who post ID questions tagged e.g. [tag:short-stories] or [tag:movie] without the ID tag. We're constantly doing tag edits on new ID questions anyway, so this wouldn't add much to it. (And even the [tag:names] tag could be misused on ID questions - "*looking for the name of a story*".) That said, if anyone has a better suggestion for the tag name, I'm all ears.

Comment: @RandalThor Well, the whole thing is a drop in the bucket! Anyway, perhaps "title-explanation", similar to "plot-explanation"?

Comment: @Skooba I made an update that removes the lumping

Comment: Upvoted after your edit. Not sure if I agree with [tag:title-explanation] - what if there are questions about story titles which aren't "why did this story have this title", like [this one](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/126276/31394)? - but the exact name of the tag will be easy to change by a mod-merge even after we've made all the necessary edits to questions.

Comment: @RandalThor It's still asking for an explanation surrounding the usage of the word. I think it fits better especially for that question, which stood out as odd to me when going through examples

Comment: Upvoted, but I would also suggest blacklisting the tag [titles] because it will get misused again even if you empty it out and put "DO NOT USE THIS TAG" in the tag wiki.

Comment: @Kevin Once it's been removed from all questions, it'll automatically disappear after a day or so and new users won't be able to recreate it. Blacklisting is normally reserved for *very* frequently misused tags, e.g. 'intrinsic' tags (for this site, [tag:science-fiction] and [tag:fantasy]).

Comment: @Randal'Thor, has an agreed usage been decided, a few of the changes you've made recently go against the tag wikis for the tags you've deleted.

Comment: @Edlothiad This answer has got a lot of upvotes, so I've started to make the required edits. Will fix the tag wikis once it's all done and dusted.

Comment: **I've now retagged all [tag:titles] questions, and rewritten the wikis for the [tag:names] tag and the new [tag:title-explanation] tag.** Let me know if I buggered anything up.